# Sum of BigDecimal(s) created from possible null Double

Tags: java, double, guava, precision

In order to avoid possible loss of precision in Java operation on `Double` objects i.e.:

```
Double totalDouble = new Double(1590.0);
Double taxesDouble = new Double(141.11);
Double totalwithTaxes = Double.sum(totalDouble,taxesDouble);
//KO: 1731.1100000000001
System.out.println(totalwithTaxes); // 1731.1100000000001
```

I wrote this code, where `totalDouble` and `taxesDouble` could be also `null`:

```
Double totalDouble = myObject.getTotalDouble();
Double taxesDouble = myObject.getTaxesDouble();
BigDecimal totalBigDecimalNotNull = (totalDouble==null) ? BigDecimal.valueOf(0d):BigDecimal.valueOf(totalDouble);
BigDecimal taxesBigDecimalNotNull = (taxesDouble==null) ? BigDecimal.valueOf(0d):BigDecimal.valueOf(taxesDouble);
BigDecimal totalWithTaxesBigDecimal = totalBigDecimalNotNull.add(taxesBigDecimalNotNull);
System.out.println(totalWithTaxesBigDecimal);
```

Is there a better way (also with third part libraries i.e. guava, etc) to initialize `BigDecimal` in this cases (zero if `Double` is `null` and `Double` value otherwise)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.  That is to say, you're still going to need to make a decision based on whether or not the value is `null`, but you can do it cleaner if you use the Optional pattern.

You can change your `getTotalDouble` and `getTaxesDouble` returns to `Optional<Double>` instead to mititgate having to do the ternary...

```
public Optional<Double> getTotalDouble() {
   return Optional.ofNullable(totalDouble);
}

public Optional<Double> getTaxesDouble() {
   return Optional.ofNullable(taxesDouble);
}
```

...then, you can use the conditional evaluation provided by `Optional` itself to evaluate and return a default value.

```
BigDecimal totalBigDecimalNotNull =
           BigDecimal.valueOf(myObject.getTotalDouble().orElse(0d));
```

A simplification would be to return `Optional<BigDecimal>` instead, as opposed to transforming the value that you want in this fashion.

As an addendum, be careful when talking about precision.  [There is standing advice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/1079354) to use either `int` or `long` instead to ensure you don't lose any coin precision.

Comment: thanks for the hint about the "Optional" usage, I think I'll use it in the future. For the use of int or long for money representation, unfortunately I can't change this choice. 
I would have liked to use integer (and count the cent) or use BigDecimal, but I work with e-commerce framework and it uses double..

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use `Optional` or not I recommend creating a static helper method so that you don't have to repeat yourself. e.g.:

```
public static BigDecimal bigDecimalValueOfOrZero(Double val) {
    return val == null ? BigDecimal.ZERO : BigDecimal.valueOf(val);
}
```